# Вопрос в знаках препинания

Tags: запятые

Дано предложение: "А бывает наоборот: отличающиеся(,) чётко разграниченные направления в медицине(,) ошибочно считают тождественными, то есть – одним и тем же"
Меня интересуют запятые. Нужны ли они в тех местах, где заключены в скобках. Ну, и нет ли в других местах пунктуационных ошибок. Спасибо всем, кто откликнется и ответит профессионально.

Comment: Alex, на сайте принято благодарить участников за все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов на свой вопрос галочкой.

Comment: Понял, большое спасибо за информацию. Не знаю, туда ли я нажал сейчас.

Comment: Еще галочку слева от ответа нажмите.

Comment: Сделано! Еще раз благодарю Вас!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: *А бывает наоборот: **отличающиеся,чётко разграниченные направления в медицине** ошибочно считают тождественными, то есть – одним и тем же.*

**Рассмотрим сочетание**: *отличающиеся, чётко разграниченные **направления** в медицине*.

Согласованные определения (причастие и причастный оборот) являются **однородными**, так как раскрывают общую тему сходства и произносятся с перечислительной интонацией. Они независимо друг от друга относятся к определяемому существительному "направления".

Падежная форма "в медицине" является несогласованным определением, после этого слова запятая не ставится. Там делается небольшая произносительная пауза, но нет грамматических оснований для постановки запятой.

**Тире** интонационное, авторское, обозначает паузу.